# How can I catch a C# AppCrash because of a native C++ DLL fail

Tags: c#, c++, .net, try-catch, crash

I have a DLL created from native c++(say XYZ.dll). I link against that DLL in a wrapper that is C++ .NET. An object of this wrapper is used in my highest level C# code.

My question is: sometimes a function in my DLL crashes and my highest level C# code crashes with AppCrash; crash module: XYZ.dll. I am trying to figure our where it is crashing my native C++ code, but that is proving to be fruitless. I was wondering if there was a way for me to catch this crash in my C# code and move on.

Comment: As much as I know you can't catch it. Even if you would disassemble it to IL and modify IL representation.

Comment: When debugging unmanaged code, it's often best to go back to old time-tested techniques like logging.  You won't get a managed exception out of an unmanaged 'crash', so the best you can do is isolate what causes the crash and avoid doing that.  Even if it turns out to be a bug in third-party code you can't control, you can at least identify an appropriate work-around.

Comment: that is not true.  you can use SEH in c#.  http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/using-structured-exception-handling-to-handle-exceptions-from-c-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the answer you are looking for but at least it will help to troubleshoot the issue.  Check out AppDomain.UnhandledException...  you should be able to catch and log the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you are debugging in Visual Studio? If not, consider installing the Windows debuggers and run your app under cdb.exe. Make sure you have symbols (.pdb) for your unmanaged component. If you run your app under the debugger (be that Visual Studio or cdb/windbg) and can repro the crash, then you should be able to get a stack trace. And since you imply that you own the unmanaged library, can I assume that you have the sources? If you are in VS then make sure to disable the Debug Just My Code setting. If you are in windbg, then the point of crash should show your stacktrace once you hit the first chance exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely "Catch" this crash.

In your C++ .NET Wrapper/Handler, wrap all calls down into the 3rd Party DLL, wrap all calls with C++ try/catch blocks. That should more than likely work.

In the event it does not, switch to using Windows structured exception handling. This will catch native Win32 exceptions and kill-them-dead. You can find Win32 doc's on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).